# Odoo on aws and docker containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, odoo

I am running odoo on an ec2 instance -aws.
The odoo code is pulled from the docker hub, running inside the ec2 via docker containers.
The problem is that the ec2 doesn't have a static IP and every time it's restarted the connection with odoo disappears.

This is at least the theory am working with.
I would appreciate other solutions or might be problems

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate an Elastic IP to your ec2 instance. This will give your ec2 a fixed public IP address

You can follow the documentation in AWS below:

[Associate an Elastic IP address with an instance or network interface.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#using-instance-addressing-eips-associating)

Take in account that there are costs associated: [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/#Elastic_IP_Addresses)

Comment: That would be the case to go with, but there are charges for that, at the moment they cannot take that

Comment: @Eric You can use a Dynamic DNS solution  like https://www.noip.com/ or https://www.dynu.com/

Comment: I'll check on this, but how would you change the odoo instance to communicate with the new ip

Comment: You specify the ip/hostname you have setup with the dynamic dns solution in your odoo instance.